# Sending output to stdout (console) in a VB.NET win form project

Tags: vb.net, stdout

I have an application with a String variable that repeated gets a Date from a database, does something with that field, then goes onto the next row.

Is there a way I can send send out some debugging information to the stdout console so I can debug better/view the progress of the program?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`Debug.WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline.aspx).

You can configure your application to use the [`ConsoleTraceListener`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.consoletracelistener.aspx):

> To direct all trace and debug
>   messages to the console while the
>   application executes, add a
>   ConsoleTraceListener object to the
>   application configuration file. Edit
>   the configuration file that
>   corresponds to the name of your
>   application, or the app.config file in
>   a Visual Studio 2005 project. In this
>   file, insert an element for a
>   ConsoleTraceListener.
>
> The following example adds a
>   ConsoleTraceListener object named
>   configConsoleListener to the Listeners
>   collection.

```
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="false" indentsize="4">
      <listeners>
        <add name="configConsoleListener" 
          type="System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
 </configuration>
```

Then you can call `Debug.WriteLine` and it will log to the output console.

Answer (score 3):

`System.Console.WriteLine` will also do the trick.

[Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdf6yhx5.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

A better option is to send it to the Debugger output window.  This will be visible while debugging the program and compiled out in a Release build.

```
Debug.WriteLine("some message")
```

Calls to Console.WriteLine will fail for a WinForms project.  Off the top of my head I can't remember if it will throw or fail silently, but it certainly won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`Debug.Writeline()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline.aspx)